# Filter Table Column By Column

Tags: javascript

How do I make sure after filtering results,it will only show available items on the next column?

I'm taking the example from this link.

```
  (http://jsfiddle.net/koalyptus/eCqG3/)
```

As you can see,on the 1st column. You will able to filter all available countries by clicking [SHOW ALL]

But,after filtering the 1st column for example I took Asia.

On the next column, it still display all available population in the list instead of one list which belongs to Asia only.--How do I get this?

Comment: Which browser are you using? The jsfiddle works perfectly here (win7 with Google Chrome 33.0.1750.154 m) - I select Asia and then have only a single row of data - Asia's. `Asia - 3,712,527,624 - 56.5 % - 10.5 % - 35.6 %`

Comment: Hmm. I meant the drop down list.

Comment: Do you want the other options in the list to disappear after you select one element? I.e `before select Items: ` [Show All], Africa, Asia, Latin America / Carribean, Middle East, North America, Oceania / Australia.  `select "Asia"`, Items remaining: Asia

Comment: Yup. this is my intention.

Comment: There's a couple of approaches that may help. Write a function that is attached to the `<select>` element's change event. **(A)** In that handler, remove all elements with an index higher than your selected item, followed by removing all elements except the last one. or **(B)** It may actually be easier to **i** clone the selected option element, **ii** remove all option elements from the select, followed  by **iii*** appending the cloned node as a child of the (now empty) select element.

Comment: Here's an example of the cloneNode approach: http://jsfiddle.net/ht9jN/ - (I don't know if emptying and re-populating the select element will cause issues with the library you're using.)